# how to handle API JSON response

Tags: apex, visualforce

This is my code for fetching event information from eventbrite. response i am getting is JSON. How can i convert this JSON response to viewable format.

```
     public void searchEvent(string pagequery)
        {
 Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/?location.address=' + pagequery);
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer###########');
        System.debug(req.getendpoint());

        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        System.debug(res.getBody());
        querys = res.getBody();    

        }}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You can create Apex class out of Json response from [JSON 2 APEX](http://json2apex.herokuapp.com)
2. Inside newly created class you will get one method called parse which you can use in following way

   ```
   JSONResponse response = JSONResponse.parse(res.getBody());
   ```
3. Once this is done you can access values as response.userid etc.

Answer (score 0):

Apex has a [JSON](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_deserialize) class which you can use. You have to call the deserialize method which will take the body of the response as an argument.